# Given any number of $n$-sided dice, the probability of rolling a sum of $k$ will not exceed $2/n$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Generate a function for the roll of an n sided die:

$$P(x)=x+x^2+x^3+…+x^n$$

such that the power of $x$ indicates the side of the die in contact with the ground.
Then, the number of ways to form the sum $k$ is the coefficient of $x^k$.
For some $i$ dice, the sum of numbers can be found by:

$$P(x)=x(1+x+x^2+…+x^n-1)$$

$$P(x)=\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}$$

$$P(x)^i=x^i(x^n-1)^i(x-1)^{-i}$$

and so gives a rough formula upon using sigma notation for $i=1$ through to $i=n$ for the coefficient of $x^k$.
I’m stuck on evaluating this, nevertheless the denominator with which I should divide by to find the probability.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.

Comment: For clarification, the numbering on the dice begins from 1, not 0. And by the probability given ‘any number’ of dice, this is the sum of probabilities when using 1,2,3,… through to k number of dice (since it is impossible for k+1)

Comment: I think what you are trying to prove is false. Consider $k=6$, with six-sided die. The probability of rolling $6$ with one die is $1/6$. The probability of rolling $6$ with two dice is $5/36$. For three dice, the probability is $10/216$. Note that $1/6 + 5/36 + 10/216$ is already greater than $2/6$. Please correct me if I am misunderstanding anything.

Comment: So, you cannot prove a bound of $2/n$. But you can prove a bound of $e/n$.